# Posterior distribution of $\sigma^2$

Tags: regression, bayesian, variance, posterior, inverse-gamma-distribution

In chapter 9 of Jim Albert's [Bayesian computation with R](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387922973) it's mentioned that, in the context of Normal Linear Regression, the posterior joint density is:

$$g(\beta, \sigma^2 | y) =g(\beta|y, \sigma^2)g(\sigma^2|y) $$

And it's stated (without proof) that the marginal posterior distribution of $\sigma^2$ ( i.e. $g(\sigma^2|y)$ ) is $Inv. Gamma((n-k)/2, S/2)$ where n = # of observations, k = # of parameters, and $S = (y-X\hat\beta)^T(y-X\hat\beta)$.

I was wondering how one get's to this (he assumed uninformative prior of $g(\beta, \sigma^2) \propto 1/\sigma^2$)?

I tried the following but got stuck:
$$ g(\sigma^2|y) = \int_{\beta} g(\sigma^2, \beta|y)d\beta \propto \int_{\beta} g(y |\sigma^2, \beta)g(\sigma^2, \beta)d\beta \propto \int_{\beta} g(y |\sigma^2, \beta)\frac{1}{\sigma^2}d\beta \\
=\int_{\beta} (2\pi)^{-n/2}(\sigma^2)^{-n/2-1}e^{-\frac{S/2}{\sigma^2}}d\beta
$$

So without doing the integral I can account for the $S/2$ (kind-of, if I estimate $S$ using $\hat\beta$), and $n/2$ in the inverse gamma. But how do I integrate, and will I then get $(\sigma^2)^{k/2}$ ?

Comment: It's a not so short story :) See Gill, _Bayesian Methods_, [pp. 79-80](https://books.google.it/books?id=Iq_epk4mtM4C&printsec=frontcover&hl=it&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: @Sergio Unfortunately this book is not available to me from my university databases...

Comment: You can read pp. 79-80 in https://books.google.it/books?id=Iq_epk4mtM4C&printsec=frontcover&hl=it&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: nope, it only lets me go until p. 74

Comment: I can read pp. 79-80.

Comment: Yes, I could too once I just searched for it, without your link. Thanks